# Find all hyperlinks to a SharePoint site collection

Tags: hyperlink, spo

I have a site collection say A with URL https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA

Will it be possible for me to find where all this URL is hyperlinked?

Means,will it be possible for me to find all the places(like other site collections and subsites) where https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteA and its inner pages are hyperlinked?

T

Comment: SharePoint out of the box is not possible. May be some 3rd party tool could, but not sure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/99845)